# IMAP and Gmail Labels

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, imap, gmail-imap

I'm trying to figure out how to add GMail labels to my app. I'm using Mailcore that doesn't support it so I want to add them my self. I've researched a bit and found this:

```
a010 FETCH 1:4 (X-GM-LABELS)
* 1 FETCH (X-GM-LABELS (\Inbox \Sent Important "Muy Importante"))
* 2 FETCH (X-GM-LABELS (foo))
* 3 FETCH (X-GM-LABELS ())
* 4 FETCH (X-GM-LABELS (\Drafts))
a010 OK FETCH (Success)
```

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/imap_extensions#x-gm-labels

What languge is this? Is that an API? How do I access it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's the IMAP protocol, defined here: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1730.txt. You can connect to an IMAP server via telnet (usually tcp port 443) and run that fetch command.

Here's an example of how to use telnet to connet to an IMAP server and run commands, such as FETCH, manually.

http://networking.ringofsaturn.com/Protocols/imap.php

Comment: So i'll need to find a way to use some sort of telnet alternative inside my Objective-c code, FETCH those labels and import them back to my Objective-c project?

Comment: No, from code you just open a socket, connect, and send/receive data. Telnet is useful to manually try out the commands yourself.

Comment: Oops. I meant tcp port _143_ not 443. And yes, Gigi's right. Using telnet is just a good way to connect to the IMAP server to test and get to know the protocol.

Comment: Ok but I still don't understand how to implement those calls in objective-c

Comment: You really want RFC3501, not 1730.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with MailCore, but if it's anything like other IMAP libraries I've worked with, it may have a function you can call to "manually" send an arbitrary IMAP command. Indy, for example has a function SendCmd that you can use for this purpose. I would imagine MailCore might have a similar function somewhere if you poke around in the documentation or source code.